# BigQuery see the entire column in results view

Tags: google-bigquery

This is likely a dumb question, but seriously, why does bigquery "..." columns in the results view? I see no way to drag the column over and see the entire value, is there a way to do this?

Comment: I was able to get it using dev tools and inspecting the html, otherwise yeah, export it somewhere else to get the full d...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other workaround regarding the display of column's content in Results View. It is BigQuery's default feature. You can file for a feature request in the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).